# UIWebView content is initially small, then expands after rotation. Why?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Environment: iOS 6.1
Xcode: 4.6.3

**Problem:** UIWebview content is initially (upon initial load) is *small*.

Rotating the device (to/from any orientation) expands (and keeps) the content to *normal size*.

Why?

How can I force it to load with with the same scale as after it rotates (to any position)?

Comment: Is it possible you're altering the value of the property `scalesPageToFit`?

Comment: Apparently it's not a client problem.  It appears to be our server, a 'back-end' issue of supporting UIWebView. The back-end guy failed to zoom the html page for the iOS from the server.   He fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the UIWebView's `shouldScalePagesToFit` property to NO will prevent it from trying to rendering the page *small*.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

I'm unable to replicate the problem you have with a simple single-view application. I would suggest that you check your app for changes to the above named property.

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned this in the comment....
It's been confirmed that our server was responsible for the initial small appearance within UIWebView.  The iOS correctly re-scaled the UIWebView's contents during re-orientation.

Our server guy made the necessary re-scaling and hence, corrected this particular problem.